# how to concatenate foreach inside xslt?

Tags: xslt

I have following structure in my xslt -

```
   <Identification>
                    <xsl:for-each select="DataPartner">                 

 <xsl:variable name="var:v30" select="userCSharp:LogicalEq(string(../../Demo/@name) , &quot;Description&quot;)" />
                        <xsl:if test="string($var:v30)='true'">
                          <Identifier>
                              <xsl:value-of select="Demo/demo/text()" />
                              <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                          </Identifier>
                        </xsl:if>
                      </xsl:for-each>

                    </Identification>
```

input xml -

```
<DataPartner>
                      <Demo name="Description">
            <demo>demo11</demo>
          </Demo>
           <Demo name="Description">
            <demo>demo12</demo>
          </Demo>
                            <DataPartner>
```

expected output-

```
demo11 , demo12
```

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate all the `demo` element text, where the `Demo` name is "Description"?

Comment: yes exactly same ,  could you please help me in this

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed, as you have an opening `demo` tag, but a closing `Demo` tag. Also, in your XSLT you do `xsl:for-each` on `DataPartner` but there is only one `DataPartner` in your XML. Can your xml actually have more than one DataPartner? If so, what should the output look like? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the intention is to to concatenate all the `demo` element text, where the `Demo` name is "Description", then this is how you might do it....

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="DataPartner">
    <Identifier>
      <xsl:for-each select="Demo[@name='Description']">
        <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">, </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="demo" />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Identifier>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: not working for me strange :( 
`position() > 1 ` not working

Comment: Try `position() &gt; 1` instead. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMeq